# ComboBox1 precedence over radio button?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make this even always work whether I check a radio button first or if I check combobox item first? Currently it only works if radio button is checked first. Thank you.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( comboBox1.Text == "Test1" && radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"my path");
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If ou want the test to be true whether the combobox text is "Test1" OR the readiobutton is checked, you need to make the test an OR instead of an AND, like so:

```
if ( comboBox1.Text == "Test1" || radioButton1.Checked)
```

If both conditions need to be true, try this (pseudocode):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ConditionFulfilled)
    {
        readThatPuppy();
    }
}

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ConditionFulfilled)
    {
        readThatPuppy();
    }
}

private bool ConditionFulfilled()
{
    return (comboBox1.Text.Equals("Test1") && radioButton1.Checked;
}

private void  readThatPuppy()
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"my path");
    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
    textBox1.Text = str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this event is only associated with the combobox event. You need to move this code into a common function and call it from both the ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event and the radiobuttons changed event.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this only works when the radio button is checked is because you have this condition in your event handler.

Try the following and see if it does what you're looking for.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( comboBox1.Text == "Test1" || radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"my path");
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: @B. Clay, I have 65 radio button,that would make me write 130 if conditions?

Comment: You could probably use a generic even handler for all the radio buttons. I would stay away from the designer with 65 radio buttons and try to add them during runtime through code.